# An occult property of chemical elements

Tags: pattern, chemistry

I have partitioned the chemical elements into two groups based on a certain
occult property that is shared by some of them, but not by the remaining ones.

The following elements have my occult property:

> arsenic, astatine, carbon, iron, krypton, neon, phosphorus, silicon, tin

The following elements do not have my occult property:

> antimony, boron, cobalt, germanium, gold, helium, lead, mercury, sulfur

Which of the following elements have this occult property?

> aluminium, fluorine, francium, gallium, oxygen, polonium.

Comment: There's nothing immediately obvious about the numerical stats and I can't find any pattern in name origins.

Comment: For solving this puzzle, you need nothing except a table with the periodic system.

Comment: So that means it's the atomic number, abbreviation, name, physical location on the table, or group.

Comment: @Engineer Toast Yes, that covers all the information you need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> none of them

because the enigmatic property is

> the ability to spell the element's name using element symbols.  For example, Arsenic is Ar+Se+Ni+C, and Silver is Si+Lv+Er.  As far as I can tell, there are only 13 elements with this property: Silver, Arsenic, Astatine, Bismuth, Carbon, Copper, Iron, Krypton, Neon, Phosphorus, Silicon, Tin, and Xenon.

Comment: Any disbelievers can try it out here: http://www.bgreco.net/periodic/

Comment: I'm glad I wrote my own script, because it's not often that I write a recursive function that works on the first try!

Comment: Regular expressions are not always the answer, but sometimes they really are the right tool for the job: http://refiddle.com/26d7